# "Advanced" calculator fail

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a calculator, but I want to be able to type in the amount of times I want the answer to be (plussed, minus, multiplied or devided). So therefor I have "Calc". So that input is the amount of times i want something to happend with the answer.

I have tried doing

```
a = print(tall1 + tall2)
```

and then making `a` an `int`, but that didnt work

```
oper = input("What operation: ")
calc = int(input("How many calculations: "))
tall1 = int(input("Type a number: "))
tall2 = int(input("Type another number: "))

if oper == ("+"):
    for num in range(calc):
        print(tall1 + tall2)
elif oper == ("*"):
        print(tall1 * tall2)
elif oper == ("/"):
        print(tall1 / tall2)
elif oper == ("-"):
    for num in range(calc):
        print(tall1 - tall2)
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your post.

Comment: What does *"calculate something several types"* mean? You want to print the same result multiple times?

Comment: I think he means different operators

Comment: I mean calculate something several times, sorry typo

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote and accept. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus.

Comment: *"doing a = print(tall1 + tall2) ... didnt work"*: Change to `a = tall1 + tall2`

Comment: `a = print(tall1 + tall2)` will always return a as `None`

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `range()` and have extra `'s at the end of your code. Correcting these two simple mistakes makes the code run correctly:

```
oper = input("What operation: ")
calc = int(input("How many calculations: "))
tall1 = int(input("Type a number: "))
tall2 = int(input("Type another number: "))

if oper == ("+"):
    for num in range(calc):
        print(tall1 + tall2)
elif oper == ("*"):
        print(tall1 * tall2)
elif oper == ("/"):
        print(tall1 / tall2)
elif oper == ("-"):
    for num in range(calc):
        print(tall1 - tall2)
```